# Postgres weird query plan when the number of records less than "limit"

Tags: postgresql, performance, sql-execution-plan, postgresql-12

I have a query that is very fast for large date filter

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT "advertisings"."id",
       "advertisings"."page_id",
       "advertisings"."page_name",
       "advertisings"."created_at",
       "posts"."image_url",
       "posts"."thumbnail_url",
       "posts"."post_content",
       "posts"."like_count"
FROM "advertisings"
  INNER JOIN "posts" ON "advertisings"."post_id" = "posts"."id"
WHERE "advertisings"."created_at" >= '2020-01-01T00:00:00Z'
AND   "advertisings"."created_at" < '2020-12-02T23:59:59Z'
ORDER BY "like_count" DESC LIMIT 20
```

And the query plan is:

```
Limit  (cost=0.85..20.13 rows=20 width=552) (actual time=0.026..0.173 rows=20 loops=1)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..951662.55 rows=987279 width=552) (actual time=0.025..0.169 rows=20 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using posts_like_count_idx on posts  (cost=0.43..378991.65 rows=1053015 width=504) (actual time=0.013..0.039 rows=20 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using advertisings_post_id_index on advertisings  (cost=0.43..0.53 rows=1 width=52) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=1 loops=20)
              Index Cond: (post_id = posts.id)
              Filter: ((created_at >= '2020-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at < '2020-12-02 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone))
Planning Time: 0.365 ms
Execution Time: 0.199 ms
```

However, when I narrow the filter (change "created_at" >= '2020-11-25T00:00:00Z') which returns 9 records (which is less than the limit 20), the query is very slow

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT "advertisings"."id",
       "advertisings"."page_id",
       "advertisings"."page_name",
       "advertisings"."created_at",
       "posts"."image_url",
       "posts"."thumbnail_url",
       "posts"."post_content",
       "posts"."like_count"
FROM "advertisings"
  INNER JOIN "posts" ON "advertisings"."post_id" = "posts"."id"
WHERE "advertisings"."created_at" >= '2020-11-25T00:00:00Z'
AND   "advertisings"."created_at" < '2020-12-02T23:59:59Z'
ORDER BY "like_count" DESC LIMIT 20
```

Query plan:

```
Limit  (cost=1000.88..8051.73 rows=20 width=552) (actual time=218.485..4155.336 rows=9 loops=1)
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.88..612662.09 rows=1735 width=552) (actual time=218.483..4155.328 rows=9 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..611461.80 rows=723 width=552) (actual time=118.170..3786.176 rows=3 loops=3)
              ->  Parallel Index Scan using posts_like_count_idx on posts  (cost=0.43..372849.07 rows=438756 width=504) (actual time=0.024..1542.094 rows=351005 loops=3)
              ->  Index Scan using advertisings_post_id_index on advertisings  (cost=0.43..0.53 rows=1 width=52) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=0 loops=1053015)
                    Index Cond: (post_id = posts.id)
                    Filter: ((created_at >= '2020-11-25 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at < '2020-12-02 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1
Planning Time: 0.394 ms
Execution Time: 4155.379 ms
```

I spent hours googling but couldn't find the right solution. And help would be greatly appreciated.

**Updated**

When I continue narrowing the filter to

```
WHERE "advertisings"."created_at" >= '2020-11-27T00:00:00Z'
AND   "advertisings"."created_at" < '2020-12-02T23:59:59Z'
```

which also returns the 9 records as the slow above query. However, this time, the query is really fast again.

```
Limit  (cost=8082.99..8083.04 rows=20 width=552) (actual time=0.062..0.065 rows=9 loops=1)
  ->  Sort  (cost=8082.99..8085.40 rows=962 width=552) (actual time=0.061..0.062 rows=9 loops=1)
        Sort Key: posts.like_count DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 32kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..8057.39 rows=962 width=552) (actual time=0.019..0.047 rows=9 loops=1)
              ->  Index Scan using advertisings_created_at_index on advertisings  (cost=0.43..501.30 rows=962 width=52) (actual time=0.008..0.012 rows=9 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((created_at >= '2020-11-27 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_at < '2020-12-02 23:59:59'::timestamp without time zone))
              ->  Index Scan using posts_pkey on posts  (cost=0.43..7.85 rows=1 width=504) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=9)
                    Index Cond: (id = advertisings.post_id)
Planning Time: 0.540 ms
Execution Time: 0.096 ms
```

I have no idea what happens

Answer (score 3):

PostgreSQL follows two different strategies in the first two and the last query:

- If there are many matching `advertisings` rows, it uses a nested loop join to fetch the rows in the order of the `ORDER BY` clause and discards rows that don't match the condition until it has found 20.
- If there are few matching `advertisings` rows, it fetches those few rows, then the matching rows in `posts`, then sorts and takes the first 20 rows.

The second execution is slow because PostgreSQL overestimates the rows in `advertisings` that match the condition. See how it estimates 962 instead of 9 in the third query?

The solution is to improve PostgreSQL's estimate:

- if running

  ```
  ANALYZE advertisings;
  ```

  is enough to make the slow query fast, tell PostgreSQL to collect statistics more often:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE advertisings SET (autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.05);
  ```
- if that is not enough, try collecting more detailed statistics:

  ```
  SET default_statistics_target = 1000;
  ANALYZE advertisings;
  ```

  You can experiment with values up to 10000. Once you found the value that works, persist it:

  ```
  ALTER TABLE advertisings ALTER created_at SET STATISTICS 1000;
  ```